# dnsmasq on virbr0 (libvirt) and network manager

Tags: libvirt, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I want to run dnsmasq on my local machine in order to configure a wildcard to resolve to 127.0.0.1 for testing purposes.

However, when I went to start dnsmasq with systemd I got the following error message:

```
[root@dhcppc4 ~]# systemctl status dnsmasq -l
● dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-10-09 21:49:58 BST; 14s ago
  Process: 2652 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq -k (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 2652 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 systemd[1]: Started DNS caching server..
Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 systemd[1]: Starting DNS caching server....
Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 dnsmasq[2652]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use
Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 systemd[1]: Unit dnsmasq.service entered failed state.
Oct 09 21:49:58 dhcppc4 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service failed.
```

Confused as to how port 53 is taken with no current DNS server running (and confirmed with `dig @127.0.0.1`), I ran `netstat -ln` and found a process listening on port 53 on address `192.168.122.1`:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*
```

An ifconfig shows that `192.168.122.1` is the virtual interface virbr0.

A quick Google search and wiki later, I understand that libvirt provides virtual networking to the host in order to abstract physical interfaces. Libvirt uses a virtual network switch through which all traffic is routed [[1]](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#Virtual_Networking). The default virtual network switch, virbr0, is created when the daemon first starts.

I can then confirm that I can send queries via DIG to dnsmasq on this interface:

```
[grobinson@dhcppc4 ~]$ dig @192.168.122.1 +short
a.root-servers.net.
j.root-servers.net.
m.root-servers.net.
b.root-servers.net.
i.root-servers.net.
k.root-servers.net.
l.root-servers.net.
d.root-servers.net.
g.root-servers.net.
c.root-servers.net.
h.root-servers.net.
e.root-servers.net.
f.root-servers.net.
```

**Question 1**: I don't understand the reason behind having dnsmasq listen on this virtual interface? For /etc/resolv.conf I can see that the DNS servers configured at the DHCP server tell the machine to direct queries to Google DNS servers. What is its use?

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I find that I can edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and add the line `dns=dnsmasq` and then restart network manager with systemd. From here on network manager is configured to direct queries to dnsmasq on the loopback address and can be seen with a simple call to dig:

```
[grobinson@dhcppc4 ~]$ dig @127.0.0.1 +short
l.root-servers.net.
g.root-servers.net.
i.root-servers.net.
...
```

The `netstat -ln` output now shows two sockets bound and listening on port 53:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**Question 2**: how come network manager can start dnsmasq on 127.0.0.1 and I can't with systemctl? Is that because the default configuration is attempting to listen on all interfaces, which fails for virbr0? I just need to state the desired interface?

**Question 3**: It looks like there are two configuration options for dnsmasq: `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and a folder `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/` where configuration files can be written. It looks like the latter is for when `dns=dnsmasq` is set and dnsmasq listening on 127.0.0.1 since editing `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` has no effect on queries to @127.0.0.1. Could the former be for dnsmasq in libvirt?

Comment: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Libvirtd_and_dnsmasq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, libvirt starts a dnsmasq instance for each of its' virtual interface bridges. This is done to provide DHCP service to VM's running in a virtual network.

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking

Essentially, the virbr bridge is created by libvirt every time you spin up a VM using the default settings. If you want to prevent this from happenning, you need to create the bridge yourself before starting up a VM and then start it up in "bridge" mode, speciying your custom bridge as the argument. Here is a man page that explains it pretty well. Look under the --network option:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaat/liaatvirtinstalloptions.htm

Every time you create a "virtual network" in libvirt, it also starts an instance of dnsmasq for it. So, again, you have to stop using libvrt's virtual networks and go manual.

Comment: I don't get it. That whole dnsmasq automation for bridges in libvirt ruins virsh net-* shell functions to complete uselessness as there can be scenarios in which you don't want to use dnsmasq. Not even an arg or switch to disable that behavior.

Comment: Read my original reply - the answer is there. In short - there is a simple way to avoid spinning up an instance of dnsmasq.

Comment: How could i overlook this? Found it elsewhere:
https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=commit;h=9065cfaa889b3512ad02560fbefb05c75349b10b

Answer (score 1):

If you want your local /etc/hosts changes to propagate to your VMs using the same interface you can simply SIGHUP the local libvirt process.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your dnsmasq instance to explicit list of interfaces you want it to listen on.

In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` you can use either interface names `interface=eth0` or interface IP `listen-address=192.168.0.1`. Even with this set, dnsmasq will helpfully bind to all interfaces, so disable that by adding `bind-interfaces` to the config file.

Alternatively, in the config file, specify interface blacklist with `except-interface=virtbr*`.

Sources:

- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Libvirtd_and_dnsmasq
- http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html
- http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq.conf.example